# How to check ADX ingestion log and queue?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

The command

```
.show ingestion failures
```

outputs errors in the ingestion process. I however did not find a way to get list of **successfully** ingested items, as well as inspect the ingestion queue (names of the items) and current status (what is being ingested at the moment). Is it possible and how to view that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADX is optimized for high throughput, therefore it is not optimized for exposing individual ingest operation tracking by default (that level of granularity puts extra load on the service).
We also do not expose detailed information on the queues, definitely not listing the ingress queue items.

You can track all the ingest operations (failed/succeeded/both) by setting up [Diagnostic Logs with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs?tabs=ingestion).

An aggregated view on your cluster via metrics is also available.
Please see [Monitor Azure Data Explorer performance, health & usage with metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-metrics#ingestion-metrics) and [Monitor batching ingestion in Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/monitor-batching-ingestion).

Comment: The Lighthingest and sdk (python at least) can show the result of ingestions with successes and failures. Is that information available via query?